# Groovy RestClient with many connections

Tags: groovy, rest-client

Using Groovy RestClient I am getting the following exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
```

As I understand that one connection has not released, so I cannot make another one.

What are the possible solutions?

Make new RestClient for every call?
Or maybe there is some pool?

Thanks!

Comment: Any example code of what you're doing?

Comment: Also, what version of HTTP-Builder are you using?

Comment: static API_SECURE = new RESTClient('http://example/api.php')
def res = API_SECURE.get([query: variables])
That is all, but it is happening for many users at the same time :|

Comment: You might want to try moving across to using AsyncHTTPBuilder http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/async.html As restclient extends HTTPBuilder, and [I found this mailing list entry](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Multiple-concurrent-requests-with-HTTPBuilder-td367900.html) which seems to be your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the REST Client uses the BasicClientConnManager which only handles one connection at one time. In order to do concurrent connections, you need to use the AsyncHTTPBuilder:

```
def httpClient = new AsyncHTTPBuilder(
        poolSize: 20,
        uri: 'https://www.mysite.com'
)
```