# Groovy: Multi-Threaded use of the RESTClient class from Codehaus

Tags: multithreading, groovy, rest-client

I'm using the RESTClient class from Codehaus (http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/index.html?groovyx/net/http/RESTClient.html) in my application, however, I'm running into issues when multiple threads try to use the client at the same time.  After some reading I found out that this is because the RESTClient class by default uses a single connection that cannot be shared by multiple threads.  The answer seems to be to use a different connection class that allows concurrent use from multiple threads (as mentioned here: [Groovy RestClient with many connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255728/groovy-restclient-with-many-connections)).  However, I can't seem to find anywhere how to tell the RESTClient class to use these other types of connections.  Is this even possible?  I'm hoping to keep the advantage of the RESTClient, so using just a generic HTTPBuilder or AsyncHTTPBuilder class instead of the RESTClient sort of defeats the purpose of the RESTClient class (unless it's possible to have the HTTPBuiler/AsyncHTTPBuilder class spit out a RESTClient connection).

Alternatively, should I be just creating a new RESTClient for each thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Alternatively, should I be just creating a new RESTClient for each thread?

yes, it's the easiest way

Comment: Well I'm not sure if this is a good idea. Time and resource consuming.

Comment: No, no results. Such connection manager is advanced structure with lots of threading, resources operation etc. I just doubt if creating it from scratch for every thread is a good idea. But have no hard evidence.

Comment: Builder instance creation is not that painful as you think. The main bottleneck are still the underlying sockets. I tested the `HttpBuilder` in several pretty high-concurrent environments, and the builder init time takes up to 5% of time for each get/post request/response

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. But still won't implement it that way.

Comment: 1st try & test, then decide. Otherwise it's just a speculation

Comment: In some cases 5% may be very important. Don't know if this is the case here. I was doing API optimization recently. Have made it 3 times faster. Not sure if it would be possible when creating the whole connection manager for every thread separately.

Comment: In my experience, if you are doing batch jobs against REST APIs, its worth using a pool of http clients, with one RESTClient instance per application thread.  Results in a very noticeable performance improvement, similar to switching to a database connection pool.  See my "ThreadSafeHTTPBuilder" answer below for a primitive implementation using DefaultHttpClient; deprecated since 4.3 but still in wide usage.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code for a subclass of HttpBuilder which will create a thread-safe pool of client connections for a single instance of ThreadSafeHTTPBuilder.

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams

class ThreadSafeHTTPBuilder extends HTTPBuilder {

    protected AbstractHttpClient createClient(HttpParams params) {
        PoolingClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager()
        cm.setMaxTotal(200) // Increase max total connection to 200
        cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20) // Increase default max connection per route to 20
        new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
def client = new ThreadSafeHTTPBuilder()
```